# Graphics driver for Intel 82865G in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find a working Windows 7 driver for the Intel 82865G graphics chipset?](https://superuser.com/questions/23123/where-do-i-find-a-working-windows-7-driver-for-the-intel-82865g-graphics-chipset)

I have a desktop PC which has an integrated Intel 82865G graphics card, and only PCI slots on the motherboard. I cannot stick another graphics card in it.

Can I get a working driver for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are no official drivers. A quick Web searching leads me to the following Intel Tech Note - see below.

You can get PCI graphics cards so are you sure you cannot add a graphics adaptor?

---

http://tinyurl.com/6zgwxvk

**Older Intel® Graphics Controllers and Microsoft Windows 7***

Windows 7* drivers are not available for the following older Intel® graphics controllers:

Mobile Intel® 915GM/GMS, 910GML Express Chipset Family

Intel® 82915G/82910GL Express Chipset Family

**Intel® 82865G Graphics Controller**

Intel® 82852/82855 Graphics Controller

Intel® 82845G Graphics Controller

Intel® 82830M Graphics Controller

Intel® 82815 Graphics Controller

Intel® 82810 Graphics Controller